# What soil can i use to plant plants in my bearded dragons cage

Tags: bearded-dragon

Im getting a bearded dragon. Im planning on planting nontoxic succulents in the cage and maybe a jade plant im struggling to figure out if i should put the soil directly in the cage or plant in pots and if so what soil should i use?

Comment: Give a thought to tgw case you may need to disinfect the cage... Then you may prefer pots :)